# cannot resolve method 'performAsync' in quickblox

Tags: android, quickblox, quickblox-android

I have updated my QuickBlox Android SDK from 2.5.2 to 3.3.0 (partial)
chat , content sdk from 2.5.2 to 3.3.0
I have done following changes 
 1. In app build.gridle file

> ```
>  compile "com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-chat:3.3.0"   
>  compile "com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-content:3.3.0" 
>  compile "com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-customobjects:2.5.2"    
>  compile "com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-location:2.5.2"   
>  compile "com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-messages:2.5.2"    
>  compile "com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-videochat-webrtc:2.5.2"   
>  compile "com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-extensions:3.3.0"
> ```

but when I am trying to singin I am getting error "cannot resolve method 'performAsync"

```
final QBUser user = new QBUser("login", "password");
```

[image]

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use same version for all QuickBlox Android SDK modules

Comment: try to clean your project after changes in build.gridle file and synchronize again